# Java run phantomjs from command line

Tags: java, command-line, phantomjs

I have a quick question: I am trying to call the following command line from a java application C:/phantomjs/phantomjs chart/chart.js

I tried doing:

```java
public static void go3(){
    Runtime rt=Runtime.getRuntime();
    try{
        final Process pr=rt.exec("cmd C:/phantomjs/phantomjs chart/chart.js");
        final int exitCode=pr.waitFor();
        if(exitCode!=0){ throw new RuntimeException("program didnt exit with 0, but with "+exitCode); }
        // System.out.println(pr.toString());
        // int exitStatus=pr.waitFor();
    }catch(IOException e){
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("done");
}
```

but I get exit code -1. I looked at various tutorials/question on stackoverflow but they all run trivial examples and I am struggling to understand how to write the part inside `.exec("what goes here?")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
public static void go4(){
    String[] command={"cmd","/k","cd /phantomjs&&phantomjs chart/chart.js"};
    Process p;
    try{
        p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        PrintWriter stdin=new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
        stdin.close();
        int returnCode;
        returnCode=p.waitFor();
        System.out.println("Return code = "+returnCode);

    }catch(IOException e1){
        e1.printStackTrace();

    }catch(InterruptedException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```